# Sum nlayers of a rasterStack in R

Tags: r, r-raster

I am working with daily observation of climate data organized in .nc files.
I read them using the stack command of the raster package. Each file (corresponding to a year) is a RasterStack element with the following characteristics:

```
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 360, 720, 259200, 365  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

each layer is the raster of values of a day.
I would like to sum the layers in order to calculate the monthly values. I believe the solution should be using calc or stackApply {raster}, but I couldn't find a way to sum from layer x to layer y or a way to subset the RasterStack before summing.

I prepared an [example file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a97crpvpa804d9x/mydata.nc?dl=0) with only 12 layers (to reduce the size).

I don't exactly know how to propose a code, sorry, but it should be something like:

```
library(raster)
setwd("myfolder")
data<-stack(mydata.nc)

datasum<- stackApply(data, ??? ,fun=sum)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `stackApply` to do this. Using your example data, it looks like the name of each raster layer is the date. You can use that to build the indices that you need to pass to `stackApply`.

The list of indices needs to have 31 1s for the January days etc.

You could do:

```
    #get the date from the names of the layers and extract the month
    indices <- format(as.Date(names(data), format = "X%Y.%m.%d"), format = "%m")
    indices <- as.numeric(indices)

    #sum the layers
    datasum<- stackApply(data, indices, fun = sum)
```

The result will be a raster stack of 12 layers.

To subset raster layers from the stack, you can do `data[[c(1,2]]`

Comment: Does this approach go well with parallelization to reduce the runtime?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue,  to compute the mean over a long time series .nc files however `stackApply` did not work for me.

I managed to solve using `calc`. So you also could use:

```
#sum the layers
datasum <- calc(data,fun=function(x) { by(x, indices, sum)})
```