# converting raster layers from month to year then merging

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I have been trying to sum my rasterlayers from my rasterstack for each month by their respective years. Similarly to this thread here: [Sum nlayers of a rasterStack in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798389/sum-nlayers-of-a-rasterstack-in-r)

I have been able to change the names of my raster layers to a date format `yy.mm.dd` using this:

```
p <- names(landcover) %>% 
  str_extract("(?<=MCD64A1.A)[0-9]{4}") %>%
  paste(outer(1:12,1:10, paste, sep="-" ), sep="-") 
  setNames(landcover, 1)
landcover
[1] "2010-1-1"   "2010-2-1"   "2010-3-1"   "2010-4-1"  
  [5] "2010-5-1"   "2010-6-1"   "2010-7-1"   "2010-8-1"  
  [9] "2010-9-1"   "2010-10-1"  "2010-11-1"  "2010-12-1" 
 [13] "2011-1-2"   "2011-2-2"   "2011-3-2"   "2011-4-2"  
 [17] "2011-5-2"   "2011-6-2"   "2011-7-2"   "2011-8-2"  
 [21] "2011-9-2"   "2011-10-2"  "2011-11-2"  "2011-12-2" 
 [25] "2012-1-3"   "2012-2-3"   "2012-3-3"   "2012-4-3"  
 [29] "2012-5-3"   "2012-6-3"   "2012-7-3"   "2012-8-3"  
 [33] "2012-9-3"   "2012-10-3"  "2012-11-3"  "2012-12-3" 
 [37] "2013-1-4"   "2013-2-4"   "2013-3-4"   "2013-4-4"  
 [41] "2013-5-4"   "2013-6-4"   "2013-7-4"   "2013-8-4"  
 [45] "2013-9-4"   "2013-10-4"  "2013-11-4"  "2013-12-4" 
 [49] "2014-1-5"   "2014-2-5"   "2014-3-5"   "2014-4-5"  
 [53] "2014-5-5"   "2014-6-5"   "2014-7-5"   "2014-8-5"  
 [57] "2014-9-5"   "2014-10-5"  "2014-11-5"  "2014-12-5" 
 [61] "2015-1-6"   "2015-2-6"   "2015-3-6"   "2015-4-6"  
 [65] "2015-5-6"   "2015-6-6"   "2015-7-6"   "2015-8-6"  
 [69] "2015-9-6"   "2015-10-6"  "2015-11-6"  "2015-12-6" 
 [73] "2016-1-7"   "2016-2-7"   "2016-3-7"   "2016-4-7"  
 [77] "2016-5-7"   "2016-6-7"   "2016-7-7"   "2016-8-7"  
 [81] "2016-9-7"   "2016-10-7"  "2016-11-7"  "2016-12-7" 
 [85] "2017-1-8"   "2017-2-8"   "2017-3-8"   "2017-4-8"  
 [89] "2017-5-8"   "2017-6-8"   "2017-7-8"   "2017-8-8"  
 [93] "2017-9-8"   "2017-10-8"  "2017-11-8"  "2017-12-8" 
 [97] "2018-1-9"   "2018-2-9"   "2018-3-9"   "2018-4-9"  
[101] "2018-5-9"   "2018-6-9"   "2018-7-9"   "2018-8-9"  
[105] "2018-9-9"   "2018-10-9"  "2018-11-9"  "2018-12-9" 
[109] "2019-1-10"  "2019-2-10"  "2019-3-10"  "2019-4-10" 
[113] "2019-5-10"  "2019-6-10"  "2019-7-10"  "2019-8-10" 
[117] "2019-9-10"  "2019-10-10" "2019-11-10" "2019-12-10"
```

Next by following the thread above, I used this code:

```
indices <- format(as.Date(names(p), format = "%Y.%m.%d"), format = "%Y") 
print(indices)
character(0)
```

However, it returns `character(0)`, as opposed to formatting by each year.

my aim is to use this code:

```
  datasum<- stackApply(data, indices, fun = sum)
```

So I am only left with years 2010 to 2019, as thats the extent of which i am working with.

Comment: I've noticed that `p` was only to create the dates. Then using the rasterstack `forest_fire`, as a variable to change its names to `p` by: `names(forest_fire) <- p`, then using the code above and removing `names(p)` for `names(forest_fire)`. Although, the code is still running I do expect this to be more successful.