# Partial summation of RasterBrick

Tags: r, netcdf, r-raster

I use the raster package to read a NetCDF file and want to process it in R. A couple of manipulations give me the RasterBrick object `r_daily` with 1461 layers that correspond to daily values over 4 years:

```
> r_daily
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 360, 720, 259200, 1461  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
> names(r_daily)
[1] "y2011.01.01" "y2011.01.02" "y2011.01.03" "y2011.01.04"
[5] "y2011.01.05" "y2011.01.06" "y2011.01.07" ...
```

Now I just want to sum over all values of each year to get the RasterBrick object `r_yearly`.

```
> r_yearly
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 360, 720, 259200, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

I am grateful for any help or hints!

Answer (score 1):

I now found a good solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798389/sum-nlayers-of-a-rasterstack-in-r) that I did not encounter before.

```
    years <- names(r_daily) %>%
      substr(2,5) %>%
      as.numeric()
    r_yearly<- raster::stackApply(r_daily, years, fun = sum)
```